# Creating analytics / demographics report from scratch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to create a Analytics / Demographics report from scratch in Ruby on Rails ? I don't want use Google analytics, I want to create the report from scratch based on my requirements.

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** I want to create that report based on the data present in my database.

Comment: You can use Ruby on Rails to do anything you want. Just track the ip & the user and save it in the database.

Comment: Thank you. I am a beginner in developing RoR based application, so a little bit more detailed explanation would be great.

Comment: I'd be more than happy to help you but your question needs to be a little bit more specific. It's a very general question. What kind of user behaviour are you trying to pull? What reports are you trying to generate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use highcharts gem, as you don't want to use google analytics.

[gem link](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/highcharts-rails)